# Devise authentication fails with 401 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I just switched from Sorcery to Devise.  Sorcery is semi-inactive and although authentication is working in rails 5---test helpers are not.  So, I decided to make the switch the Devise.  I've been getting the dreaded 401 error:

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized
```

I have seen many questions regarding this...but, none of those answers helped me.

My question is a bit misleading because you will immediately assume I have some remnants of the Sorcery install.  I might, but Ive thoroughly checked it all.

1 - If I use the forgot password functionality within Devise I will be auto logged in after changing my password---However, I can not log in using those sme credentials...get the 401 error.

2 - If I completely clear existing passwords (because I'm pretty sure sorcery encryption is diff than devise encryption) and update password using devise OR

3 - I have traced the path taken for authentication inside Devise and my problem surfaces when the following method is hit:

```
def valid_password?(password)
  Devise::Encryptor.compare(self.class, encrypted_password, password)
end
```

It seems that encrypted_password != password even though the password was successfully updated using devise.

As part of following the auth path inside Devise I should also point out that I am using the Devise method user.skip_confirmation! which manually confirms the user---so, user confirmation should not be part of this issue.

I am using custom Devise views (although have not altered them yet).  I have also generated a custom sessions controller because I think/thought this issue might be related to Pundit policy.  However, I am skipping policy verification in the application controller using the following...so, Pundit should not be a problem:

```
after_action :verify_authorized, except: :index, unless: :devise_controller?
after_action :verify_policy_scoped, only: :index, unless: :devise_controller?
```

cookies_serializer has been brought up a number of times in other answers...I have tried :json, :marshal, and :hybrid with no affect.

So, authentication is failing because Devise::Encryptor.compare(self.class, encrypted_password, password) returns false.  But, if Devise saved the new password---how can compare not return true.  And, yes---I have entering the credentials correctly.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  So, attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation is no longer needed in Devise---and, was responsible my problem.  By setting attr_accessor :password my app was creating a password=() method, which was overriding the same method in devise.  The result was no matter what my password ended up being ''.  I originally found this by creating my own password setter:

```
def password=(new_password)
  @password = new_password
  self.encrypted_password = password_digest(@password) if @password.present?
end
```

Which is the same exact method in Devise internals.  With this method my password saved and I was able to log in.  I thought this was strange...so, I removed my custom method, and the attr_accessor and authentication continued to work.  So, basically the attr_accessor overrode the devise method, then I created a setter method that overrode the attr_accessor method.

It was a lot of work and in the end was something so simple.  I hope this helps someone else.  I have some additional testing to do and if I find anything else I will amend this.